# Error installing ROS on MacBook Pro OS X 10.6.7

Tags: macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello i am trying to install ROS on a MacBook pro running OS X 10.6.7 and i am getting this error!
Any help please?

```
Bootstrapping ROS build
Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ros', 'ros_comm']                         
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/Users/Diamadis/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110703-002019
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ros', 'ros_comm'] to:
['rosunit', 'rospack', 'rosmake', 'rosemacs', 'rosdep', 'roscreate', 'rosclean', 'rosboost_cfg', 'rosbash', 'test_rospack', 'test_rosmake', 'test_roslib', 'test_rosdep', 'test_roscreate', 'roslib', 'roslang', 'rosbuild', 'mk', 'xmlrpcpp', 'roswtf', 'rostime', 'message_filters', 'cpp_common', 'topic_tools', 'rostopic', 'rostest', 'rosservice', 'rosrecord', 'rosparam', 'rosout', 'rosnode', 'rosmsg', 'rosmaster', 'roslaunch', 'rosgraph', 'rosconsole', 'rosbagmigration', 'rosbag', 'test_topic_tools', 'test_roswtf', 'test_rostopic', 'test_rostime', 'test_rostest', 'test_rosservice', 'test_rospy', 'test_rosparam', 'test_rosnode', 'test_rosmsg', 'test_rosmaster', 'test_roslib_comm', 'test_roslaunch', 'test_rosgraph', 'test_roscpp_serialization_perf', 'test_roscpp_serialization', 'test_roscpp', 'test_rosbag', 'test_ros', 'test_crosspackage', 'perf_roscpp', 'roscore_migration_rules', 'std_srvs', 'std_msgs', 'rosgraph_msgs', 'rospy', 'roslisp', 'roscpp_traits', 'roscpp_serialization', 'roscpp']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#No packages to install
}}}
[ rosmake ] rosdep successfully installed all system dependencies               
[ rosmake ] Starting >>> tools/rospack                                          
[ rosmake ] Finished <<< tools/rospack                                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosemacs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosemacs  No Makefile in package rosemacs              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosboost_cfg [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosboost_cfg  No Makefile in package rosboost_cfg      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbash [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbash  No Makefile in package rosbash                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> mk [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
[ rosmake ] All 20 linesoslib: 15.2 sec ] [ xmlrpc... [ 2 Active 7/68 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  [rosbuild] Building package roslib
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/Diamadis/ros/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/Diamadis/ros/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /Users/Diamadis/ros/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/Diamadis/ros/ros/bin/rosboost-cfg", line 35, in <module>
      rosboost_cfg.main()
    File "/Users/Diamadis/ros/ros/tools/rosboost_cfg/src/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 328, in main
      raise BoostError("Cannot find boost in any of %s"%search_paths(options.sysroot))
  rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError: "Cannot find boost in any of [('/usr', True), ('/usr/local', True)]"
  CMake Error at /Users/Diamadis/ros/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:848 (message):
    rosboost-cfg --include_dirs failed
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:5 (rosbuild_add_boost_directories)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package roslib written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/Diamadis/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110703-002019/roslib/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib [FAIL] [ 15.26 seconds ]                        
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package roslib. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp [PASS] [ 81.85 seconds ]                      
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 9 packages with 1 failures.                                   
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /Users/Diamadis/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110703-002019         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 442, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1167, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 556, in <module>
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 547, in rosinstall_main
    
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 462, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/Diamadis/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
Diamadis-MacBook-Pro:~ Diamadis$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10467/error-installing-ros-on-macbook-pro-os-x-10.6.7/) by [DiTz](https://answers.ros.org/users/778/ditz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems it cannot locate you boost installation, which is you installed from macports should be at:

```
/opt/local/include/boost/
```

Your install seems to search in `/usr/...` directories. Can u make sure these environment variables are set

```
export CPATH=/opt/local/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/local/lib
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

The run the install again after verifying that you have boost installed correctly. For further instructions, please consult this [https://https://github.com/wjwwood/ros-osx/wiki](https://github.com/wjwwood/ros-osx/wiki)

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1